# For performing a multi-object validation in Swing, should failed validation be reported via exception or by returning a Result object?

Tags: java, swing, validation, exception

I am designing a Swing window for managing the information about a NonPlayerCharacter entity. The design is intended to be easily extensible. The main body of the editor form is contained inside a tabbed pane, so that future extension modules can add tabs to extend the editor.

The tabbed pane can be populated by tabs that implement the `NPCEditorTab` interface. Part of the "Saving" process involves a loop that cycles through the tabs calling the `verifyFields()` method on each, ensuring that all fields are properly completed (I supposed to keep with convention I should rename this to `validateFields()`). If the validation of all tabs is successful, another loop calls the `saveNPC()` method for each tab, instructing them to write their data to the NPC object.

My question is: What is the best method for tracking the validation of each tab so that the *reasons* for a failed validation can be reported to the user?

I have two options:

## 1) Have the method throw a `ValidationException`.

This `ValidationException` would contain information regarding the source tab and which form fields were incomplete and why, allowing the editor to report this to the user as a single message. I would probably collect exceptions as they occur in a collection and complete all the validations before reporting the results from all the tabs at once (to prevent a case of the user receiving an Error from Tab 2, fixing that, then oh, you also have an error in tab 4, etc).

Reading on here and elsewhere suggestions that using exceptions for flow control is bad design, which is why I'm hesitant to use this option.

## 2) Have the method return a `ValidationResult` object.

These `ValidationResult` objects would be added to a collection after each iteration and examined. They would contain a boolean flag (`isValidated()`), a source String identifying the source tab, as well as a List of Strings describing reasons for validation failure.

In either case validation results would be reported to the user in a single dialogue.

I don't personally see a problem with the first option, as to me (a self-taught Java enthusiast) it seems to the least performance impacting (an object is only generated in the event of a failure, as opposed to *every time no matter what* as with the second option).

I have no experience with developing a custom API (I sort of enjoy feeling my way along and finding ways to handle problems on my own), but I am attempting to design this program to be extensible so that I can easily add functionality later without massive modifications to the existing code (I ran into this problem on my first iteration of this project, each new feature made the base code more and more convoluted until it became unmanageable).

That is the reason I am handling form validation this way, I am just wary of including validation reporting in the individual tabs because I don't want the user to receive a unique notice for each individual tab. However, if you think the best method is to do just that (IE when a tab's validation fails, it notifies the user itself via `JOptionPane` and then returns `false` which terminates the validation check), let me know.

## Addendum

Upon outside advice, I have decided to scrap the entire multi-tab validation scheme and instead validate on individual form elements by capturing lost-focus events and forcing the user to correct invalid input immediately after it is entered.

Comment: I think both scenarios have merit, what you want to do though is avoid using `Exception`s to control flow.  I would also argue that an invalid field is not exception, but is defined and legal state...

Comment: The main reason I am conflicted despite the overwhelming apparent opinion of the web is that there are examples of the Java API using exceptions for flow control (for instance, `DataInputStream`s throw an `EOFException` to indicate that the end of the file has been reached).

So I'm seeking individual opinions of my specific case.

Comment: I would argue it throws an `EOFException` to deal with the use case of some note paying attention to what they are doing or a corrupt stream.  If done correctly (AFAIK), you shouldn't need to "rely" on `EOFException` to tell you when you've reached the end of the stream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer 2) option. You can see for example SpringMVC validation logic.

Each field of form could be annotated with necessary validation e.g. @Email, @NotEmpty etc.
On validate there is a collection of errors (could be empty if all the fields are valid). Then each filed could be marked somehow with error message particular for the field (empty if it's valid).

On check there could be a message about errors. On clising the message would be good to point (e.g. set focus) on the first invalid control.